# Excel triple (multiple) VLOOKUP with a concatenated VLOOKUP value over two worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to create a `VLOOKUP` that is over 2 worksheets and looks at three look up values where one of them is a concatenated with a `-` in the middle.

Base Data is too big to put in here (30k char limit) so here is the file:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b475e4206e9b1c01519b4e6405fbf2f420180208112525/49c87b

In the Transform tab I have tried using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Data!D10:BB300,MATCH(A4&"-"&B3,INDEX(Data!D7:AO7,0)),MATCH(Transform!B2,Data!A11:B300,0))
```

But get `#N/A` even though I have pointed it to the correct cells.

Expected output is also in the file.

A quick explanation:

In the `Data` tab I have a row which has dates such as `Jan-16`, `Feb-16`, `Mar-16` etc

Also in the `Data` tab I have a row which contains either `Actual` or `Budget`

Also in the `Data` tab I have the value `Total Alpha`

In the `Transform` tab I have it laid out like so:

```
_______________________
|Actual | Total Alpha | 
-----------------------
|       |16     |17   |
-----------------------
|Jan    |       |     |
----------------------- 
|Feb    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Mar    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Apr    |       |     |
-----------------------
|May    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Jun    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Jul    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Aug    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Sep    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Oct    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Nov    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Dec    |       |     |
-----------------------
|       |       |     |
-----------------------
|Budget |       |     |
-----------------------
|       |18     |     |
-----------------------
|Jan    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Feb    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Mar    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Apr    |       |     |
-----------------------
|May    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Jun    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Jul    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Aug    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Sep    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Oct    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Nov    |       |     |
-----------------------
|Dec    |       |     |
 ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅
```

And using a triple `VLOOKUP` I want to be able to look at the (for example):
`Actual` & `Total Alpha` & `Nov` & `17` (using something like `A4&"-"&B3` to merge the values as the data tab has values like `Nov-17`) and find the relevant value in the `Data` tab.

Comment: The second argument of `MATCH` must be an *array*, not a matrix. The last section of your formula in your question: `MATCH(Transform!B2,Data!A11:B300,0)` will return `#N/A` regardless of what the actual data is because `Data!A11:B300` is not an array.

Comment: An array is just a one dimensional matrix. E.g. `A11:B11` and `A11:A300` are arrays but `A11:B300` is a matrix.

Comment: @Matt The answer depends on where `Transform!B2` can be found. Is it to be found and matched in `Data!A11:A300` or in `Data!B11:B300`? Afterwards you should adjust your formula.

Comment: A11:B300 preferably as its a massive data source, but B11:B300 could be an option (i have tried this BTW and still get #N/A)

Comment: Matt, did you ever get your problem solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In range B4 put

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$1:$Z$22,MATCH(Transform!$B$2,Data!$A$1:$A$22,0),MATCH(DATEVALUE(Transform!$A4&Transform!B$3),Data!$1:$1,0))
```

Drag to fill to C15.

In B19 put

```
=INDEX(Data!$AA$1:$AL$22,MATCH(Transform!$B$2,Data!$A$1:$A$22,0),MATCH(DATEVALUE(Transform!$A19&Transform!B$18),Data!$1:$1,0)-COLUMN(Data!Z1))
```

Drag to fill down to B30.

This indexes a lookup range and then finds the row (e.g. total alpha) and column  (date) of interest and returns the intersect value.

[image: Formulas in sheet]

Change the value in B2 if you want a different line e.g. Total Beta

[image: total beta in b2]

Version 2: Dynamic lookup of Actual and Target - can be tidied up somewhat

Create two named ranges

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to open name manager and then add

Name: ActualRange

RefersTo:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$1,0,0,ROWS(Data!$1:$22),MATCH(Transform!$A$17,Data!$2$2,0)-1)
```

Name: BudgetRange

RefersTo:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$1,0,MATCH(Transform!$A$17,Data!$2$2,0)-1, ROWS(Data!$1:$22),MATCH(Transform!$A$17,Data!$2$2,0))
```

Then in `B4` dragged to fill to `C15` goes:

```
=INDEX(ActualRange,MATCH(Transform!$B$2,Data!$A$1:$A$22,0),MATCH(DATEVALUE(Transform!$A4&Transform!B$3),Data!$1:$1,0)
```

Then in `B19` dragged to fill to `B30` goes:

```
=INDEX(BudgetRange,MATCH(Transform!$B$2,Data!$A$1:$A$22,0),MATCH(DATEVALUE(Transform!$A19&Transform!B$18),Data!$1:$1,0)+ROWS($A$19:$A19))
```

There is some scope to further reduce the indexed ranges which are currently set at entire rows.

Comment: Good answer.  Small suggestion: both formulas - simplify the  index to `=INDEX(Data!$1:$100,` or as many rows as required.  For the `B19` formula also delete the `-COLUMN(Data!Z1)` (taken care of by INDEXing into whole rows, you are already MATCHing a whole row)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks. Was habit I indexed whole column. Have changed to A1:A22. True, more efficient. Re: the -COLUMN. That I think needs to stay, unless I re-write entire formula as I changed the indexed area to Data!$AA$1:$AL$22 but, as you note, I am still indexing the entire row 1 for the date. So I have to remove the number of columns prior to the start of the index area. I shifted the index because the Budget data starts at this column AA. So it was more to fit the layout of the data.

Comment: @QHarr Phenomenal answer :) I will award bounty in 3 hours (when it lets me) worked perfect after i tweaked it for my increased dataset!

Comment: @QHarr Actually, this misses a lookup, it doesnt dynamically look for `Actual` or `Budget` (`A2` & `A17` in `Transform` tab looking at Row 2 in `Data` tab)

Comment: No because in the sample you gave these are fixed. I  can adjust later today. That is a simple case of IF "Actual" INDEX ......ELSE INDEX.......I will fix it up tonight.

Comment: @QHarr Sorry i should have been more clear, Yeh because next year the budget will be 19 and the actual will include the 18, hmm that actually should work, let me have a play with it as well

Comment: You would only need to change the 18 to 19 but I think I get your point. I will fix this eve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164995/discussion-between-qharr-and-matt).

Comment: Hmmm, having issues with the range formulas. Also in my actual document the data tab goes down to like 300 rows and the total parts are in the middle somewhere so i wanted something to look at the whole tabs and find whats needed and they change location every time its refreshed]

Comment: I added comments in the chat link. Let me know if there is something further to do :-)

Comment: @QHarr After some modification (due to my data model, not the answer) I managed to use the updated answer to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

These **array** formulas should work for your needs.

**You *must* commit them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.**

`Transform!B4` should be (copy it through to the remaining cells in the `Transform!B4:C15` range):

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$1:$AL$22,MATCH(Transform!$B$2,Data!$A$1:$A$22,0),MATCH(DATEVALUE($A4&" 1, "&B$3)&$A$2,Data!$A$1:$AL$1&Data!$A$2:$AL$2,0))
```

`Transform!B19` should be (copy it through to the remaining cells in the `Transform!B19:B30` range):

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$1:$AL$22,MATCH(Transform!$B$2,Data!$A$1:$A$22,0),MATCH(DATEVALUE($A19&" 1, "&B$18)&$A$17,Data!$A$1:$AL$1&Data!$A$2:$AL$2,0))
```

[image: picture of results]